# Node Cluster Example Fails in Production Build

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, babeljs

Why does this node cluster example code taken from the nodejs website, fail in production?

Link to Example Code: https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster

```js
const cluster = require('cluster');
const http = require('http');
const numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  console.log(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

  // Fork workers.
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // changed from numCPUs to 2
    cluster.fork();
  }

  cluster.on('exit', function(worker) {
    console.log(`worker ${worker.id} died...`);
    cluster.fork(); // reset
  });

} else {
  // Workers can share any TCP connection
  // In this case it is an HTTP server
  http.createServer((req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end('hello world\n');
  }).listen(8000);

  console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
}
```

It will run fine using the command `node server.js`
However, if it is built using `babel build` and then run it will fail with the error below. Same thing when deployed to Heroku. How can I make this work in production?

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/server/undefined'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: try removing node_modules, then `npm install` again..

Comment: Why are you building it with Babel exactly? What is the babel build command? I can't see a reference to it on the babel website.